# Show by an example that Cauchy's Theorem does not hold separately for the real and imaginary parts of $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $f=u+iv$ be analytic inside and on a simple closed contour $\gamma$. Show by an example that Cauchy's Theorem does not hold separately for the real and imaginary parts of $f$.

Honestly I have nothing to show as prelim here. Any comment would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're asked to make an example, and quite often the first step to making an example is to make a non-example. Have you tried integrating any analytic function at all, and inspected the real and imaginary parts?

Comment: If it is analytic then the integral is zero right? given the assumption above,

Comment: note "for the real and imaginary parts of f"?

Comment: That's actually my problem, I don't know how to use Cauchy's Theorem on real part only and on the imaginary part only.

Comment: You aren't asked to use Cauchy's theorem. You are in fact asked to show that it is wrong to use Cauchy's theorem. Do you know how to compute integrals without using Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: yes, parameterization or the use of primitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be the square with corners $0,1,1+i,i$. Then
$$ \int_{\gamma} z \, dz = 0, $$
but
$$ \int_{\gamma} \Re(z) \, dz = \int_0^1 x \, dx + \int_1^{1+i} 1 \, dz + \int_{1+i}^i x \, dx + \int_{i}^0 0 \, dz = i, \\
\int_{\gamma} i\Im(z) = i\int_0^1 0 \, dx + i\int_1^{1+i} \Im(z) \, dz + i\int_{1+i}^i 1 \, dz + i\int_{i}^0 \Im(z) \, dz = -i  $$

Comment: when to use $dx$ and $dz$?

Comment: It depends on the lines. When it's a horizontal line, $dz=dx$, when vertical, $dz=i \, dy$. I didn't replace the vertical ones since the integral of a constant can be done without using a parametrisation.